# Find what std::convert::try_into, converts to

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I am learning Rust and here is the sample from the book

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

 fn main() {
   let a: i32 = 10;
   let b: u16 = 100;
 
   let b_ = b.try_into()
             .unwrap();
 
   if a < b_ {
     println!("Ten is less than one hundred.");
   }
 }
```

Author says `b.try_into()` converts `b` to i32. But where do we specify this in code? b_ is not given an explicit type, so why would a u16 get converted to i32 and not to a u32 or something else?
Thanks.

Comment: From my tests, it seems that the rust compiler is just clever and realizes that later on, `a < b_` is performed, and uses that as a type suggestion for `try_into` as no other type signature is provided. It's worth noting that this code doesn't work with `b_ < a`.

Comment: Thanks Rust seems to infer the type based on its usage later in the program. As I change the type of `a` in the above program, the type of `b_` changes accordingly.

Comment: It's called type inference and it's a very helpful feature of rust language, as you don't have to specify (sometimes very complex) types when compiler could figure out what they should be. I agree that in this example it is pretty vague and this code would be more readable if you explicitly gave a type to `b_`. rust-analyzer can show you types infered by the compiler, so you can configure your editor to show it to you, if you find it easier.

Comment: Reading the same book and came here to ask the same question . Thanks for beating me to it, by 5 days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust has a quite smart compiler and it can look at nearby code to determine what type a variable should get. This is called **type inference**.

If you explicitly want to set the type that the `.try_into()` function should convert, you can put the type in the usual position.

```rust
let b_: i32 = b.try_into().unwrap();
```

You also need to remember that you cannot specify any type for conversion because they are manually implemented in the Rust standard library.

My guess is that the compiler looks at the bottom if statement and infers that `b_` should be a i32 (So that it can perform the if check with `a` which it already knows is an i32).

I also tested that reversing the condition i.e `if b_ > a` causes a compile error. I guess it is because it wants to know what type `b_` is before going for `a`

Comment: You're right. If you write `a>b`, what actually called is `a.gt(b)`. To call appropriate function `gt`, you need to know the type of `a`. However, if `a` is known as `i32`, the only implementation of `gt` for `i32` is `fn gt(&self, other: &i32) -> bool`. So compiler can infer type of `b`.